# Missing PageStatusBar SharePoint 2016

Tags: 2016, status, sp.ui

For the `SP2013` I used the following javascript to show messages:

```
var msId = SP.UI.Status.addStatus('Message:', 'A message');
SP.UI.Status.setStatusPriColor(msId, 'red');
```

I migrated (and upgraded to 2016) the farm on a test server where the posted code does not work. `msId` is always `null`. This due to the following code in `init.js`:

```
function addStatus(g, h, e, f) {
    var a = document.getElementById("pageStatusBar");
    if (a != null ) {
        a.setAttribute("aria-live", "polite");
        a.setAttribute("aria-relevant", "all");
        var b = _createStatusMarkup(g, h, true, f);
        if (!e)
            a.appendChild(b);
        else {
            var c = a.getElementsByTagName("SPAN")
              , d = c.length > 0 ? c[0] : null ;
            if (d != null )
                a.insertBefore(b, d);
            else
                a.appendChild(b)
        }
        if (a.childNodes.length == 1) {
            StatusIdWithTopPriority = b.id;
            StatusColorWithTopPriority = 1
        }
        a.style.display = "block";
        return b.id
    }
    return null
}
```

This means that the element `pageStatusBar` does not exist...

Comparing oslo.html and seattle.html I found the difference, one has it the other does not. The point is that the two files of the old 2013 and the new 2016 match, so how it is possible that the end UI is different?